# Pi camera issue

Tags: picamera

I'm using raspi 3b and I'm not getting the camera option in the preferences menu, I[image] have tried updating the os also.

Comment: There is no option in more recent Pi OS - have you tried to use the camera? Assuming its a genuine Pi camera!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you downloaded the new "bookworm" image, which auto-detects the camera by default. In theory, you should be able to run something to test it like:

```
libcamera-hello
```

In my case (Pi4B and v2 cam), when I upgraded to bookworm, the auto-detect did not seem to work! I was able to work around this by changing this line in `/boot/config.txt`

```
camera_auto_detect=1
```

to

```
camera_auto_detect=0
dtoverlay=imx219
```

and rebooting. ([ref](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#if-you-do-need-to-alter-the-configuration))

I'd start with `libcamera-hello` and see what that tells you. You could also run `libcamera-still --list-cameras` just to see if the camera is detected or not. Good luck!

Comment: Per my original post, this has been tried. The changes suggested produce a blank screen using libcamera-hello and the camera is detected using libcamera-still --list-cameras. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED -- see below

I installed a fresh Rpi Bookworm Desktop on a RPi4b and the suggested change to /boot/config.txt did not solve the issue of the RPi camera module failing using rpicam-hello.  My /boot/config.txt has these lines:

```
camera_auto_detect=0
dtoverlay=imx219
#start_x=1
```

and

```
vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0

libcamera-still --list-cameras
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : imx219 [3280x2464 10-bit RGGB] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10)
    Modes: 'SRGGB10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [206.65 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                             1640x1232 [41.85 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                             1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                             3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
           'SRGGB8' : 640x480 [206.65 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                      1640x1232 [83.70 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                      1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                      3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
```

So it looks like the camera is detected by libcamera but running rpicam-hello produces a blank screen.

I then changed /boot/config.txt to this:

```
#camera_auto_detect=0
#dtoverlay=imx219
start_x=1
```

and rebooted ...

and then

```
vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0
```

and

```
libcamera-still --list-cameras
ERROR: rpicam-apps currently only supports the Raspberry Pi platforms.
Contributions for other platforms are welcome at https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpicam-apps.
```

Is there a solution to this?

SOLVED -

I booted to Bullseye and the camera works fine using lib camera-hello, confirming this is not a hardware issue. I then compared the /boot/config.txt of both Bullseye and Bookworm and found this line in Bookworm:

```
disable_fw_kms_setup=1
```

After commenting that line out and rebooting, rpicam-hello successfully produces an image. After this change, the camera detection is

```
vcgencmd get_camera
    supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
libcamera-still --list-cameras
    Available cameras
    -----------------
    0 : imx219 [3280x2464 10-bit RGGB] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10)
        Modes: 'SRGGB10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [206.65 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                                 1640x1232 [41.85 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                                 1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                                 3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
               'SRGGB8' : 640x480 [206.65 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                          1640x1232 [83.70 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                          1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                          3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
```

I'm not sure why vcgencmd get_camera does not detect a camera but libcamera-still --list-cameras does.

Here is the rpicam-hello output:

```
$ rpicam-hello
[0:14:06.379745490] [1934]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+118-563cd78e
[0:14:06.437260652] [1937]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:39 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:14:06.439272720] [1937]  WARN RPI vc4.cpp:390 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:14:06.440148681] [1937]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:444 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media4 and ISP device /dev/media1
[0:14:06.440236440] [1937]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1142 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
Made X/EGL preview window
Mode selection for 1640:1232:12:P
    SRGGB10_CSI2P,640x480/0 - Score: 4504.81
    SRGGB10_CSI2P,1640x1232/0 - Score: 1000
    SRGGB10_CSI2P,1920x1080/0 - Score: 1541.48
    SRGGB10_CSI2P,3280x2464/0 - Score: 1718
    SRGGB8,640x480/0 - Score: 5504.81
    SRGGB8,1640x1232/0 - Score: 2000
    SRGGB8,1920x1080/0 - Score: 2541.48
    SRGGB8,3280x2464/0 - Score: 2718
Stream configuration adjusted
[0:14:06.938210141] [1934]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 1640x1232-YUV420 (1) 1640x1232-SBGGR10_CSI2P
```

Comment: I read through this several times, trying some of the same things. I finally realized that I had done an in-place `dist-upgrade` from Bullseye to Bookworm. I got the config.txt from the raspberrypi image for bookworm, and uncommented the `disable_fw_kms_setup=1` line - now it outputs exactly like your dumps.